# How to use a Stripe token in ruby code to create an account with Stripe::Account.create()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I can [create a new stripe connect account](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create?lang=ruby#create_account-company-address-line1) with

```rb
require 'stripe'
Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc'

Stripe::Account.create({
  type: 'express',
  country: 'US',
  email: 'jenny.rosen@example.com',
  capabilities: {
    card_payments: {requested: true},
    transfers: {requested: true},
  },
})
```

I understand I can provide that account with a [test address](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing) using a 'token' called `address_full_match`. But I have no idea what that 'token' is nor how to use it in ruby code, that is, I do not know what ruby code to write to use this 'token'

I tried the obvious to generate/access a token:

```
Stripe::address_full_match
NoMethodError: undefined method `address_full_match' for Stripe:Module
from (pry):10:in `__pry__'
```

How can I use this 'token' in ruby code (specifically, in `Stripe::Account.create()`) ?

## Further attempts

#### Attempt 1

If we search the documentation for any instances of `enabled": true` it returns zero results, but if we search for instances of `enabled": false` we get 16 results. So the documentation doesn't provide a single example creating an account with either `charges_enabled: true`, nor with `payouts_enabled: true`, which is surprising since that's predominantly what developers want to do - create account functional accounts (not dysfunctional ones)

[image]

#### Attempt 2

I tried placing address_full_match in the 'Address line 1' field of the web UI. But it still results in `payments_enabled: false`

Answer (score 1):

You will get it from StripeCheckout JS client
you have to include js script from stripe

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
```

Again create a script and In the js script you have to  write like

```
StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: "<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>",
    locale: "auto",
    name: "XYZ",
    description: "XYZ Description",
    email: "<%= current_user.email %>",
    billingAddress: true,
    zipCode: true,
    token: function(token) {
      console.log("Stripe Token : " + token.id)
    }
  });
```